# Using complex operations in query method of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

Let say I have below code,

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2' : ['A', 'X', 'D', 'Y', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'X', 'D', 'A']})
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2' : ['A', 'X', 'D', 'Y', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'X', 'D', 'A']})
number = dat['col1'].values[dat.shape[0] - 3]
dat1.query("col1 == @number")
```

now instead of using `@number` in the last line, I want pass entire calculation `dat['col1'].values[dat.shape[0] - 3]` in the `query` method.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is your use case? [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) does not support such complex expression.

You can however use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a callable, which enables you to use a dynamic expression in a pipeline:

```
dat1.loc[lambda d: d['col1'].eq(d['col1'].values[d.shape[0] - 3])]
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
7     8    X
```